# Getting Text from Qtreewidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview, pyside2, qtwidgets

I have a QTreeWidget that has three columns. When the user clicks a QPushButton, what they've selected on a QListWidget is added the the QTreeWidget.

I want to check if the value selected on the QListWidget is already present on the QTreeView. How'd I do this?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
...
selected = self.aui.version_listWidget.currentItem().text()
check_list = []
root = self.aui.queue_treeWidget.invisibleRootItem()
child_count = root.childCount()
for i in range(child_count):
    item = root.child(i)
    check_list.append(item.text(0))
if not selected in check_list:
    .... #Add the selected item to the queue_treeWidget....
```

Would this be the right approach or is there a better way to do this??

Comment: You say that your QTreeWidget has 3 columns, and since the QListWidget has only 1 column, in which of the columns is that item added? In addition, what row is added and who will be the parent of the item? question leaves many doubts, so a [mcve] should help you understand what you're trying to do

Comment: The first column.... I'm looking to see if the first column is containing the data that's selected in the listWidget

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?